# flowExecutionUrl appending twice while using th:action tag in thymeleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-webflow, thymeleaf

I am using thymeleaf with Spring webflow and spring mvc. I am trying to get application url by 
`flowExecutionUrl` . But when I print `flowExecutionUrl` in span I am getting the url that is like

```
/SWF/loginflow.htm?execution=e2s1
```

but when I pass the same in `th:action` my project name got appended twice. Like this

```
/SWF/SWF/loginflow.htm?execution=e2s1
```

below is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.thymeleaf.org/dtd/xhtml1-strict-thymeleaf-spring3-3.dtd">
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
  <body>
    <div>
      <div style="width: 1330px; height: 100px;">
        <div id="header" th:include="'/header'::headerfream"></div>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 1330px; height: 500px; position: absolute; top: 110px;">
        <form action = "#" th:action="@{${flowExecutionUrl}}" method="POST">
          <div>
            <table>
              <tr><td><span th:text="${flowExecutionUrl}"></span></td></tr>
              <tr>
            <td>
              <p>User Name</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                  <input type="text" name="name" id="name"  />
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
            <td>
              <p>Password</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                  <input type="password" name="password" id ="password" />
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
              <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Tom for your answer . I found the solution

```
<form id="myForm" th:action="${flowExecutionUrl}"
       th:object="${userDetail}" method="post">
       <input type="hidden" name="_eventId" value="loginCredentialsEntered" />
```

And my action will be

/SWF/loginflow.htm?execution=e3s2_eventId=loginCredentialsEntered

Answer (score 0):

The`th:action` uses the `@{...}` syntax, which rewrites the URL. Since the `flowExecutionUrl` starts with a `/`, the URL is rewritten relative to the context root of your application. The context path `/SWF` is prepended to the URL.

The span does not use this `@` syntax and thus just writes the original value of `flowExecutionUrl`.

You should remove the context path from the `flowExecutionUrl` and let Thymeleaf prepend the context path using the `@` syntax, so your application is not dependent on the context path.

Source: [Thymeleaf Standard URL syntax](http://www.thymeleaf.org/standardurlsyntax.html)

Answer (score 0):

Found this answer [here](http://forum.thymeleaf.org/URL-expression-with-webflows-flowExecutionUrl-td4026105.html):

It works with webflow and thymeleaf very well.

Use server-relative URLs as explained here: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/html/Using-Thymeleaf.html#link-urls

This would look like:

th:href="@{'~' + ${flowExecutionUrl}}"